# How should I use a Join table in Doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'll try to explain my issue as good as possible. I've got a bunch of modules in my project that all have attachments. Because I didn't want to make a seperate attachment table for each of these modules, the idea was to have one general attachments table and corresponding Entity.

```
attachments
- id
- name
- location
- fileType
```

In order to be able to seperate the attachments from eachother, I've made a reference (join) table.

```
attachment_references
- id
- type (mail, order, ticket etc.)
- parentId (mailId, orderId, ticketId)
- attachmentId
```

And then I've got the tables for orders, mails and tickets respectively.

However, I do not know how to set up my entities to make this work. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With doctrine you can use class inheritance. Create a base `attachment` class and then one special class for each use case that inherits from the base class. The inheriting class will contain the relations to other entities, while the base class contains the fields that are the same for all.

Doctrine will create a separate table for each of them, but you don't really have to worry about that.

Have a look at this link: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html